# Where do I find the documentation about ".diskdefines"

Tags: custom-distributions

AFAIK I need to include a `README.diskdefines` into my custom Ubuntu distribution. In every tutorial I found is something like this included:

> Create a file called README.diskdefines with the following content
>
> ````
> #define DISKNAME  Ubuntu Remix
> #define TYPE  binary
> #define TYPEbinary  1
> #define ARCH  i386
> #define ARCHi386  1
> #define DISKNUM  1
> #define DISKNUM1  1
> #define TOTALNUM  0
> #define TOTALNUM0  1 ```
> ````

So far, so good. But I'm not able to find any documentation about that file and what the defines stands for or if there are more options to use. Maybe the community can help me and point me in the right direction.

One of the tutorials/walkthroughs I am using is this one:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: @waltinator Thank you for your comment but I have to say it has absolutely nothing to do with my question: 1) I've put the "code" I am referring to into my question. 2) You don't need to know how accurately I "followed" this RP, because I am asking for help finding the documentation about a specific thing, which I mentioned in my question. 3) There are no error messages because I am asking for documentation after searching myself for a few days. Don't take that as an aggressive comment: Did you even read my question or did you just see an external and pasted a comment on that?